# Hide and unhide rows with date in column using Togglebutton Excel 2016

Tags: vba, togglebutton, excel-2016

I have tried about 20 different codes, trying to edit them to meet my specifications but have failed.

I have a spreadsheet of data. One column titled "Complete" will either have a date or not have a date (mm/dd/yyyy).

I am trying to write a code for using the ToggleButton to hide and unhide rows with date and leave it alone if there is no date.

Comment: Welcome to SO as you have recently joined. I am happy to have answered your very first question. As per traditions of SO I would highly appreciate your feedback on the lone answer posted by me.

Comment: I have edited program to meet your requirement. Minor change carried by you may not fully address your requirements. Please go through the edit and would appreciate the feedback. Though changes are minor but I was stuck up in some other problems and hence it was delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This.
Assuming Your Dates are in Column E.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        'This area contains the things you want to happen
        'when the toggle button is depressed
        For Each c In Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    Next
    Else
    'This area contains the things you want to happen
    'when the toggle button is not depressed
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E" & LastRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: snapshot showing toggle action]

**EDIT 27-06-2016**
Modified the program slightly to meet OP's requirement.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_ClickRV()
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        'This area contains the things you want to happen
        'when the toggle button is depressed
        For Each c In Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next
    Else
    'This area contains the things you want to happen
    'when the toggle button is not depressed
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E" & LastRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll test it on Monday at work. I up-voted but it doesn't show (says I need 15 or more for my vote to show publicly). If this one works, I'll click the check or let you know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Liz Woolfolk You will have to wait for up-voting, But you have the right to accept the answer. You will see a check mark on the left side of answer below the down voting triangle. When you click on it , it will turn a green mark from a grey mark. This is the one thing which only you can do. This is SO way of conveying thanks. Please take your time to verify the answer as per your requirements. Then if it reasonably meets your requirement, please accept the answer. I shall be happy if it works for you.

Comment: @Liz Woolfolk I have also uploaded the working file [Hide Unhide rows on toggle action soq ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5ffu163y3i755m/hide%20unhide%20rows%20on%20toggle%20action%20soq.xlsm?dl=0) You can tweak with it and refer it for any syntax difficuly. If the rows are hidden then these will unhide on the first click and next click on Toggle button will again  hide them.

Comment: I tested it this morning and it works great, only it does the opposite of what I want it to. I want to hide the rows WITH dates; this hides rows without dates. The dates are formatted as short date. Thank you.

Comment: @Liz Woolfolk  I am modifying the program as per your requirement and shall inform you as soon as I have finished with it.

Comment: Thank you. I just made some minor changes and got it to work: 
    If c.Value <> "" Then
I changed "=" to "<>"

Comment: @LizWoolfolk Please test thoroughly this change won't work. It leaves hidden rows hidden and do not unhide all the rows at the next click as it do for rows with date. Only first date is unhidden.

Comment: It seems to work. All the rows where column "J" contains a date hide and unhide when I press the toggle button. After I changed "=" to "<>" I kept "TRUE" and "FALSE" in the original positions and it seems to be doing what I need.

Comment: @LizWoolfolk It does not work for me without the modifications suggested by me. [Hide Unhide rows on toggle action soq V270616  ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzav4d2p7qa5rcs/hide%20unhide%20rows%20on%20toggle%20action%20soq%20v270616.xlsm?dl=0). But you should give me due credit by accepting my answer for leading you to a right solution.Nice If your modification works for you. All the best- Cheers-)